# How to take 1000 lines of codes in muliple cells in Jupyter to Paragraphs Zeppelin Notebook?

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin

I want to copy-paste the code from Jupyter to zeppelin notebook.

I have multiple cells in jupyter notebook and I want to copy it to Zeppelin notebook without doing manually for each cell to paragraph.

Is there a way to do this in quicker way.